# Why can't I fit this simple tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a very simple tensorflow model.

However, I can't seem to train the model to give the desired output.

Example code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

input_values = np.array([
    [[0.3], [0.3], [0.2]],  # Sum 0.8
    [[0.2], [0.3], [0.4]],  # Sum 0.9
    [[0.9], [0.05], [0.05]],  # Sum 1.0
    [[0.1], [0.1], [0.9]],  # Sum 1.1
    [[0.2], [0.5], [0.5]],  # Sum 1.2
])

target_values = np.array([
    [0.8], [0.9], [1.0], [1.1], [1.2]
])

targets = tf.Variable(target_values, trainable=False)

inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, None, 1))

w0 = tf.get_variable('w0', shape=(1, 8), initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer())
b0 = tf.get_variable('b0', shape=8, initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer())

w1 = tf.get_variable('w1', shape=(8, 1), initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer())
b1 = tf.get_variable('b1', shape=1, initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer())

output = tf.reshape(inputs, (-1, 1))
output = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(output, w0) + b0)
output = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(output, w1) + b1)
output = tf.reshape(output, (5, 3, 1))
output = tf.reduce_sum(output, axis=1)

loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(output, targets)

feed_dict = {inputs: input_values}

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

for _ in range(1000):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=feed_dict)

print('final loss : %0.2f' % loss.eval(feed_dict))
print('output : \n%s' % output.eval(feed_dict))
```

However, after 1,000 training iterations, it comes out as something like:

```
[array([[ 1.16963911],
       [ 1.15914857],
       [ 0.75045645],
       [ 0.75721866],
       [ 0.97209203]], dtype=float32)]
```

But my desired output is:

```
[array([[ 0.8],
       [ 0.9],
       [ 1.0],
       [ 1.1],
       [ 1.2]], dtype=float32)]
```

I would have hoped that such a simple model would fit very precisely and in a small number of training iterations.

The model is flexible enough to match the desired output. Setting the weights to these values will give the desired output:

```
w0 = tf.Variable([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=tf.float32)
b0 = tf.get_variable('b0', shape=8, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

w1 = tf.Variable([[1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], dtype=tf.float32)
b1 = tf.get_variable('b1', shape=1, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
```

How can I:

- fit the model more accurately.
- fit the model in as few iterations as possible?

**Update:**

If I change the activation function from tf.nn.relu to tf.nn.sigmoid it can make a reasonable fit after 100,000 iterations (59 seconds on my machine).

Here is the output:

```
[[ 0.8082366 ]
 [ 0.906322  ]
 [ 1.04254854]
 [ 1.09336698]
 [ 1.21020865]]
```

- Why would a sigmoid function perform better in this scenario?
- Why does a sigmoid seem to train faster than the relu function in this scenario?

Comment: Please share the *exact* model you use for the problem - can't figure it out from your linked code.

Comment: @desertnaut Thanks for looking at my question. I have simplified the code and placed it in the question, instead of linking to gist.

Comment: I changed `relu` to leaky relu with alpha=0.1, and learning rate to 0.05, and I got reasonable fit (`loss<1e-4` within 1k iterations) 12 out of 20 trials.

Comment: @Richard_wth Thanks! I've had lots of fun learning about leaky relus and elu's. I think I prefer the elu as I don't like having to set the parameter of the leaky relu. It makes me think of bowels.

Comment: Using elu seems to be 10x faster than using the leaky_relu!